# Why are exceptions used for rejecting promises in JS?

Tags: javascript, promise

The specification I'm referring to is at http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/.

When using `then()`, you can either return a promise, and reject the promise when you desire, or you can throw an exception to reject a promise.

Why wasn't the api designed in such a fashion where for the `then` function, it is passed a resolve and reject function like the original promise constructor?

Exceptions are heavy in many languages (and I assume in javascript too) so it seems odd they are using them as a choice for flow control. Creating a whole new promise object and returning it, just to reject it, adds to code bloat IMO. Debugging becomes harder too in case of an exception is thrown (such as syntax errors, or if function is being called on a undefined object, etc.)

Comment: You don't _have_ to throw an exception to reject a promise, but if you do throw one the result is rejection.

Comment: [You are missing the point of promises](http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) tl;dr: You **do not** want to write code that is now handling both thrown exceptions *and* promise rejections, all of them should be handled at `.catch()`.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-are-promises-and-why-should-i-use-them) of 2 channel error handling compared to 1-channel error handling and is a huge advantage over callbacks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why wasn't the api designed in such a fashion where for the then function, it is passed a resolve and reject function like the original promise constructor?

Actually, the API in that spec emerged as a consensus amongst various implementations. However, some points that might have led to this are:

- `then` is a rather functional method. It's callback only should receive one data argument, the result value of the promise.
- Passing additional `resolve`/`reject` functions to the callback does not work well with multiple arguments or even variadic functions.
- `then` is usually used as a plain mapping function. You simply `return` the new value, no `resolve` is needed.
- When you really want to do something asynchronous in your callback where you could make use of `resolve`/`reject`, you better should use a promise anyway - which you simply can return then.

I once implemented a Promise lib with optional `resolve`/`reject` arguments, but it was tedious to use - and I seldom needed them because of #4. Using them was error-prone, you could easily forget something (like handling errors, or progress events) - just like the people who are manually constructing and returning deferreds that are resolved from promise callbacks, instead of calling `then`.

> Exceptions are heavy so it seems odd they are using them as a choice for flow control.

They're not really meant to be used for control flow (like branching, loops etc) but for *exception handling*: [rejections are exceptional](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/promises-guide#rejections-should-be-exceptional). Most Promise developers wanted to implement them as an alternative for synchronous (blocking) code - where IO was always throwing exceptions, so they adapted this. Rejections are still explained as the asynchronous equivalent to `try … catch`, though their monadic nature could be utilized in mightier ways and higher-level applications.

> Creating a whole new promise object and returning it, just to reject it, adds to code bloat IMO.

There's not much difference between `return new RejectedPromise(…)`, `return reject(…)` and `throw Error(…)`.

> Debugging becomes harder too in case of an exception is thrown (such as syntax errors, or if function is being called on a undefined object, etc.)

Most Promise developers seem to see this as an *advantage* actually - (unexpected) exceptions even in asynchronous code will be caught automatically, so they can be handled instead of blowing up the program (unnoticed). See also [exception handling, thrown errors, within promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19528705/1048572) and [acceptable promise pattern for 'LOUD' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17866672/1048572).