# How to optimize this Node.js + q code to prevent callback hell?

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, q

I am using **Q** to prevent callback hell but I have reached a part of my code that I don't know how to arrange:

I am searching for scheduled messages to be delivered. For each of them, I try to send them one by one and if it could be sent, removes it from the database. The ugly part is to have a **then() inside a for loop**. This way I end up having nested promises instead of nested callbacks!!!! Suggestions?

```
appLog.debug("Looking for scheduled messages");
var messages = messageService.findScheduled()
.then(function(messages){
    appLog.debug("found [%d] stored messages",messages.length);
    for(var i = 0; i<messages.length; i++){
        messageService.send(msg.namespace, msg.message, msg.data)
        .then(function(result) {
            if (result == constants.EVENT_EMIT_SENT) {
                appLog.debug("Message [%s] sent!!!", msg._id);
                messageService.remove(msg._id)
                    .then(function(result) {
                         appLog.debug("Message deleted: [%s]", msg._id);
                    })
                    .fail(function(err) {
                        appLog.error("The message couldn't be deleted: [%s]", msg._id);
                    });

            }else if (result == constants.EVENT_EMIT_NOT_SENT_AND_NOT_STORED) {
                appLog.debug("Message [%s] not sent", msg._id);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: One way is by not using `q` and using `bluebird` instead. `q` is slow.

Comment: Did I somehow miss `let msg = messages[i]`?

Comment: @majidarif: Using bluebird doesn't solve your code layout, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ugly part is to have a then() inside a for loop

No, that can happen. Though the functional programming style of promises usually leads to using `.map()` with a callback anyway :-) Looping is a control structure, and does *require* nesting (except you [use exceptions for control flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24956713/1048572), i.e. branching). What you don't have to do is to nest promises in promise callbacks, though.

I'd simplify your loop body to

```
function sendAndDelete(msg) {
    return messageService.send(msg.namespace, msg.message, msg.data)
    .then(function(result) {
        if (result == constants.EVENT_EMIT_SENT) {
            appLog.debug("Message [%s] sent!!!", msg._id);
            return msg._id;
        } else if (result == constants.EVENT_EMIT_NOT_SENT_AND_NOT_STORED) {
            appLog.debug("Message [%s] not sent", msg._id);
            throw new Error("Message not sent");
        }
    })
    .then(messageService.remove)
    .then(function(result) {
         appLog.debug("Message deleted: [%s]", msg._id);
    }, function(err) {
         appLog.error("The message has not been deleted: [%s]", msg._id);
    });
}
```

Now you can do something like

```
messageService.findScheduled()
.then(function(messages){
    appLog.debug("found [%d] stored messages",messages.length);
    return Q.all(messages.map(sendAndDelete));
})
.then(function() {
    appLog.debug("all messages done");
});
```

Comment: Hi Bergi! Thanks for your solution. I am testing it but with this line -> return Q.all(messages.map(sendAndDelete)); the method sendAndDelete is never called. If I remove Q.all, leaving: return messages.map(sendAndDelete), it works although I see the "all messages done" in the logs before "Message [%s] sent!!!" . Do you know why? it should be the last message. Why doesn't Q.all work?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `messages.map(sendAndDelete)` calls it but `Q.all(messages.map(sendAndDelete));` doesn't, except there's something else like a syntax error. If you omit it (and don't return a promise fro the `then` callback), then it doesn't know there is something to wait for and just resolves the next promise with `undefined`, calling the "done" message immediately. Notice that I have updated `sendAndDelete`, it needs to return a promise of course as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, one way to clean it up would be to defined a named function:

```
function SuccessfulSend(result) {
        if (result == constants.EVENT_EMIT_SENT) {
            appLog.debug("Message [%s] sent!!!", msg._id);
            messageService.remove(msg._id)
                .then(function(result) {
                     appLog.debug("Message deleted: [%s]", msg._id);
                })
                .fail(function(err) {
                    appLog.error("The message couldn't be deleted: [%s]", msg._id);
                });

        }else if (result == constants.EVENT_EMIT_NOT_SENT_AND_NOT_STORED) {
            appLog.debug("Message [%s] not sent", msg._id);
        }

    }
```

and then:

```
.then(SuccessfulSend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply refactoring your functions into named functions and trying to make better use of promise chaining would be a vast improvement.

```
var messageService, appLog, constants;

appLog.debug("Looking for scheduled messages");

messageService.findScheduled()
  .then(function(messages){
    appLog.debug("found [%d] stored messages", messages.length);
    messages.map(processMessage);
  });

function processMessage(msg) {

  msg.data.dontStore = true;
  messageService

    .send(msg.namespace, msg.message, msg.data)

    .then(function(result) {

      if (result !== constants.EVENT_EMIT_SENT) {
        throw new Error(constants.EVENT_EMIT_SENT);
      }

      appLog.debug("Message [%s] sent!!!", msg._id);
      return removeMessage(msg);

    })

    .fail(function(err) {
      appLog.debug("Message [%s] not sent", msg._id);
      throw err;
    });

}

function removeMessage(msg) {
  return messageService.remove(msg._id)
    .then(function() {
      appLog.message("Message deleted: [%s]", msg._id);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      appLog.message("The message couldn't be deleted: [%s]", msg._id);
      throw err;
    });
}
```