# How can I properly use promises so my code isn't so nested?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

This is my code. It continues to be very nested. I am using `bluebird` if that matters.

```
Promise.each BrowseNodes, (BrowseNode) ->
  amazonClient.browseNodeLookup
    browseNodeId: BrowseNode.browseNodeId
  .then (lookupResult) ->
    childNodes = lookupResult[0].Children[0].BrowseNode
    Promise.each childNodes, (childNode) ->
      amazonClient.browseNodeLookup
        browseNodeId: childNode.BrowseNodeId
        responseGroup: 'TopSellers'
      .then (results) ->
        items = results[0].TopSellers[0].TopSeller
```

Comment: You don't have to inline functions. Why don't you define them beforehand and put into variables? E.g. `onError = ...`, `onBrowseNodeSuccess = ...`

Comment: You can use chaining instead of nesting checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305267/best-way-to-handle-nested-promises-bluebird

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [How to optimize this Node.js + q code to prevent callback hell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26383057/1048572). You cannot avoid nesting completely when you want to loop. And there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for getting rid of this waterfall effect, you can change something like this:

```
asyncService.doSomething()
.then(function(res) {
  asyncService.doSomethingElse(res)
  .then(function(secondRes) {
    asyncService.doAThirdThing(secondRes)
    .then(function(thirdRes) {
      // continue
    });
  });
});
```

to this:

```
asyncService.doSomething()
.then(function(res) {
  return res;
})
.then(function(res) {
  return asyncService.doSomethingElse(res);
})
.then(function(secondRes) {
  return asyncService.doAThirdThing(secondRes);
})
.then(function(thirdRes) {
  // etc.
});
```

This solution works because Promise methods return promises themselves.

**This is a just an syntactic implementation detail, but the code does the same thing.**

If you're using ES6 along with CoffeeScript, try using a library like [co](https://github.com/tj/co) to leverage synchronous-looking async code (by using generators).

You can also use something like [promise-waterfall](https://github.com/dotSlashLu/promise-waterfall), or see if there are any backfill libraries available for the upcoming ES7 async/await.

### edit

To handle `Promise.each`:

```
.then(function() {
  return Promise.each(/* do stuff */);
})
.then(function(result) {
  // do stuff
});
```