# Stop error propagation in Bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

How can I stop a thrown error from propagating all the way down the chain?  It shows in my `catch()` block but it doesn't stop and crashes the server with an uncaught exception.

I am running this as part of a node cron job (node-cron) as:

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var cron = require('../lib/cron')

var c = new cronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('Cron starting');
  mycode.run();
}, function() {
  console.log('Cron executed');
}, true);
 c.start();
```

In my cron.js

```
  module.exports = {
    run: function() {
      return job.getAndStore().catch(function(e) {
        // This prints but it keeps on going so to speak - it doesn't 'catch', just notifies me
        console.log('ERROR', e); 
      });
    }
  };
```

Console dump:

```
Cron starting
ERROR [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Cron starting
Uncaught Exception
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have to do this which I know not quite right:

```
try {
  run();
} catch(e) { 
  console.log('Now it stops')
}
```

The `run()` is part of some cron library that doesn't have any promise support so I am wrapping it in the function to call it.

*Edit* As I think my issue is related to subsequent calls I believe it has to do with how I handle the Mongo connection on 2+ calls:

```
    //  Create a Mongo connection
Job.prototype.getDb = function(id) {
  var self = this;
  return new P(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (!self.db) {
      return Mongo.connectAsync(self.options.connection)
      .then(function(c) {
        self.db = c;
        debug('Got new connection');
        resolve(c);
      });
    }
    debug('Got existing connection');
    resolve(self.db);
  });
};

// Fetch stuff
Job.prototype.getAndStore = function(c) {
  return this.getDb().then(function() {
    throw new Error('Boom');
  });
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*it doesn't stop and crashes the server*"? Where exactly does the error get thrown? If your `catch` callback gets called you should be safe.

Comment: You have another problem in your code - show us the stack trace.

Comment: Added more code - It prints out my error in the catch block of the promise but then 'goes on' so to speak resulting in the entire app crashing. I am not sure where my mistake is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `catch` callback is only executed the first time. You are getting the uncaught exception in the second run of the cron job, and it looks like your `job.getAndStore()` does not return a rejected promise there but `throw`s synchronously. It shouldn't, it [should always return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887856/1048572).

You can use [Bluebirds `Promise.try`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisetryfunction-fn--arraydynamicdynamic-arguments--dynamic-ctx----promise) to automatically catch such exceptions and transform them into a promise rejection. Or you wrap your `getAndStore` function in [`Promise.method`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisemethodfunction-fn---function):

```
var safeGetAndStore = Promise.method(job.getAndStore.bind(job));

module.exports = {
  run: function() {
    return safeGetAndStore().catch(function(e) {
      console.log('ERROR', e); 
    });
  }
};
```

---

In your specific case, the problem was that your `job` did cache the `db` connection and returned that when it was already available - but you needed to return a promise with a `.then` method. You should simply cache the promise itself:

```
Job.prototype.getDb = function(id) {
  if (!this.db) {
    this.db = Mongo.connectAsync(self.options.connection);
  return this.db;
};
```

Comment: Ok - the safe method does the trick. If I don't do that then only the first cron call gets caught and any subsequent calls doesn't. I had not realized that this cron module went down to the seconds so the stack trace was the result of 2 normal subsequent calls. I wonder why only the first call get caught though though

Comment: In the first call for some reason it did not throw an exception, but returned a rejected promise. If you showed me your `getAndStore` function, I could tell you more about that :-)

Comment: I found my issue - I am creating a mongo connection and saving it but it was not a promise on subsequent calls. I have wrapped the thing in a `P(resolve, reject)` call though perhaps there is a better way to handle this sometimes async situation

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately you have used [an antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) to solve this. Have a look at my answer update

Comment: What I am trying to do in the getDB call is store the connection and not need to use it in the return call  in order to do `return this.db.collection('abc')` calls rather than `this.getDb().then(function(db) { return db.collection('abc'); });`

Comment: No, the point is that you always need to return a promise (even if it is already fulfilled with the stored connection), not sometimes a promise and sometimes a connection - as the code that expects to call `.then()` on it doesn't work (as we've seen).

Comment: But it is a promise all the time no? The above you see is the code I fixed to make it work. The original had the issue you are talking about. But I think this is a new question so I add it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794251/how-to-reuse-a-mongo-connection-with-promises

Answer (score 0):

Use `done`, at least if bluebird implements it properly it will work as you expect.

*`catch(..)` is just alias for `then(null, ..)` which is promise transformer that creates **another** promise for further processing.*

So following should work for you:

```
  module.exports = {
    run: function() {
      return job.getAndStore().done(null, function(e) {
        // This prints but it keeps on going so to speak - it doesn't 'catch', just notifies me
        console.log('ERROR', e); 
      });
    }
  };
```