# How to reuse a mongo connection with promises

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, bluebird

How can I change things around in my db connection call so that I can do `db.collection()`:

```
// Create a Mongo connection
Job.prototype.getDb = function() {
  if (!this.db)
    this.db = Mongo.connectAsync(this.options.connection);
  return this.db;
};

// I want to be able to do this
Job.prototype.test = function() {
  return this.db.collection('abc').findAsync()...
};

// Instead of this
Job.prototype.test = function() {
  return this.getDb().then(function(db) {
    return db.collection('abc').findAsync()...
  });
};
```

My code always calls `getDb` so the connection does get created so that is not an issue. ex:

```
this.getDb().then(test.bind(this));
```

But I actually string many of these calls around so looking for a cleaner approach.

This works - just wondering if there an overall better approach to dealing with this.

```
Job.prototype.getDb = function(id) {
  var self = this;
  return new P(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (!self.db) {
      return Mongo.connectAsync(self.options.connection)
      .then(function(c) {
        self.db = c;
        debug('Got new connection');
        resolve(c);
      });
    }
    debug('Got existing connection');
    resolve(self.db);
  });
};
```

I suppose this is really just a mongo connection issue, perhaps not just promises. All the Mongo examples I see either just make all their calls inside of the connect callback or use some framework like Express and assign it on start.

Comment: I'm afraid not, because how else would you know that a connection was successfully and asynchronously established?

Comment: @SecondRikudo - the connection is there because I always call `getDb` - see my edit. Having the connection is not an issue - mostly cleaning up is.

Comment: For cleaning up, bluebird provides `.dispose()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to do this
>
> ```
> return this.db.collection('abc').findAsync()
> ```

No, that's impossible when you don't know whether the database is already connected or not. If you might need to connect at first, and that is asynchronous, then `this.db` must yield a promise, and you'll need to use `then`.

Notice that with Bluebird you can shorten that code a bit, and avoid that verbose `.then()` callback by using the [`.call()` method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#callstring-propertyname--dynamic-arg---promise):

```
Job.prototype.getDb = function() {
  if (!this.db)
    this.db = Mongo.connectAsync(this.options.connection);
  return this.db;
};
Job.prototype.test = function() {
  return this.getDb().call('collection', 'abc').call('findAsync');
};
```

Comment: It would be great if you could mention the disposer pattern, maybe `.disposer` and proper resource management. Caching the connection this way is kind of risky.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: now you have already mentioned them :-) I'm not sure though how disposable resources would be cached however, or do you mean that they shouldn't be at all (only internally to mongo)? It might be worth if you could write your own answer…

Comment: I am not clear why my method is a no though. Seems to work fantastic. I hear anti pattern but frankly at that point I am wanting to get into chaining mongo methods which is just going to be its own thing. Isn't it creating the `self.db` connection to be set before the next chained promise?  I am not seeing that issue though it could be a timing thing.

Comment: I am basically wanting to recreate what the process would be in Express/Hapi where the connection is created on start then used in chaining.