# Error handling in Q promise

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, q

I'm a bit confused understanding Q promise error handling. Let's say I have the following functions (for demonstration only):

```
function first() {
    console.log('first');
    var done = Q.defer();
    done.resolve('first');
    return done.promise;
}

function second() {
    console.log('second');
    var done = Q.defer();
    done.resolve('second');
    return done.promise;
}

function third() {
    console.log('third');
    var done = Q.defer();
    done.resolve('third');
    return done.promise;
}

function fourth() {
    console.log('fourth');
    var done = Q.defer();
    done.resolve('fourth');
    return done.promise;
}

function doWork() {
    return first().then(function() {
        return second();
    }).then(function() {
        return third()
    }).then(function() {
        return fourth();
    });
}

doWork().catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Everything went fine.

Now that if in **second, third** or **fourth** function, I've got some errors (thrown by an async call for example), I could catch it gracefully.

For example, if in **second, third** or **fourth** function, I add:

```
throw new Error('async error');
```

The error is caught. Perfect!

But what makes me confused is that if the error is thrown in first function, the error is not caught and that breaks my execution.

Please someone tell me why or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Only exceptions in `then` callbacks are caught by promise implementations. If you `throw` in `first`, the exception will bubble and would only be caught by a try-catch statement.

That's exactly why asynchronous (promise-returning) functions [should *never* throw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887856/1048572). Instead, reject the promise you're returning (`done.reject(…)` or `return Q.reject(…)`). If you don't trust your function, you can use `Promise.resolve().then(first).…` to start your chain.

Comment: Also you can start your chain with `q.fcall(first).then(second)...`

Comment: @the4lt: Yeah, sure, I forgot it's a Q-specific question. `resolve().then(…)` is essentially the same but more portable.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the logic that can break in a `try` block and `reject` the promise with the error in the `catch` block.

```
var def = q.defer();
try {
  // sync or async logic that can break
}
catch (ex) {
  q.reject(ex);
}
return def;
```