# Reject versus Error for input validation

Tags: design-patterns, promise, bluebird

What are the cons and pros of implementing a promise function/method in the following way? -

Return a promise only if all input parameters pass validation. Otherwise, throw `TypeError`.

---

I used both of the following approaches in the past...

- Simply throwing an error: `throw new TypeError('Argument "bla-bla" is invalid...')`
- Returning a rejection: `return Promise.reject(new TypeError('Argument "bla-bla" is invalid...'))`

Now I am refactoring a library for that, to make it more consistent, and want to know the good/bad sides of either approaches first.

P.S. I have added label `bluebird` to this question, even though it is not directly related to it, but because the `bluebird` community tends to have the best expertise in such matters.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for the links. The second one does provide a good answer to this. But if someone still wants to offer a more specific answer for the input validation here, it'll be fine also :)

Comment: [This answer by Patrick Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490952/1048572) provides some discussion of distinguishing operational vs programmer errors, but as you can see from the downvotes on it it's very controversial. The community-accepted best practice is to always return a promise, just like an `async function` would.