# promise catch not working

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

**employeeData.js**

```
function getById(id) {
    return dbPromise.one(); // using pg-promise
}
```

**employeeService.js**

```
function getInfoById(id) {
    return employeeData.getXYZ(id); // purposefully calling a function that does not exist in the employeeData module
}
```

**employeeApi.js** // Express route function

```
const getInfoById = (req, res) {
    employeeService.getInfoById(123)
    .then(response => {
         res.json(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
         res.json(err); // this is not being triggered
    });
}
```

In the `employeeService` above I purposefully mis-typed the function name  and I think it should throw an undefined error for calling a function `getXYZ` that does not exist in the `employeeData.js`. However, the catch block in `employeeApi.js` is not called.

Can you suggest what I might be missing here?

Comment: FYI, `function getInfoById() {....}` in employeeService.js needs the parentheses in its definition that I show here that your code in your question does not show.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, just edited it. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think it should throw an undefined error for calling a function that does not exist

Yes, it does that. It throws an exception, it does not return a promise. As such, there is no promise object on which the `then(…).catch(…)` methods could be invoked.

> However, the catch block is not called.

There is no `catch` block, it's just a method call - which doesn't happen because there's an exception. To catch it, you would need an actual `try`/`catch` block.

But that would look weird, and that's the reason why [promise-returning functions should never throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490346/should-i-throw-an-error-or-return-a-rejected-promise-inside-an-async-function?noredirect=1&lq=1). You *could* wrap the code with the mistake in a `new Promise` executor which would catch them, but the simpler choice is to use `async`/`await` syntax which guarantees to always return a promise (and reject it in case of an exception in the function body).

```
async function getInfoById {
    return employeeData.getXYZ(123);
}
```