# Promise.all wrapper which can trap errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have this verbatim in a simple script:

```
Promise.all(links.map(function (l) {
  return Promise.resolve(require(l).r2gSmokeTest())
     .then((v:any) => ({path: l, result: v}));
}))
.then(function(results){

})
.catch(function(e){

}):
```

the problem is that if the `require()` call throws an error for whatever reason, the promise chain won't catch it.

is the simplest thing to do to avoid this to wrap Promise.all in a function, like so:

```
const getAllPromises = function(links){
   return Promise.resolve(null).then(function(){
       return Promise.all(links.map(function (l) {
         return Promise.resolve(require(l).r2gSmokeTest())
         .then((v:any) => ({path: l, result: v}));
}));
```

it seems to me that maybe Promise.all should have a different API, something like:

```
Promise.all(function(){
   return values.map(v => whatever);
});
```

that way any errors can be trapped, if Promise.all is not called within a Promise chain...

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Bergi seems like you figured it out, sorry it wasn't that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `async function` which can't throw - it will only return a rejected promise when an exception happens:

```
Promise.all(links.map(async function (l) {
  const v: any = await require(l).r2gSmokeTest();
  return {path: l, result: v};
}))
```

In general, the expectation for any function that does something asynchronous is to always return a promise and [never throw synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887856/1048572). Your `map` callback should adhere to that - and `try … catch (e) { return Promise.reject(e); }` around the `require` call if necessary. You might also consider using a helper function that works like [Bluebird's `Promise.try`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html).

Comment: hmmm, but if you do Promise.all().then() in this case, will the `then` catch the promise if an error is raised in the `async` function? I am not sure if it will

Comment: Ok I tested, this works, upvoted, but I am not sure *why*. If you explain more why it works that would be good

Answer (score 1):

Your `require()` is happening on the map level outside of Promise context, that's why it gets propagated immediately to the global level, so if you just wrap it into a `new Promise` it should handle the error as expected:

```
Promise.all(links.map(function(l) {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(require(l).r2gSmokeTest())) // <-- here
      .then((v: any) => ({
        path: l,
        result: v
      }));
  }))
  .then(function(results) {

  })
  .catch(function(e) {

  }):
```

Comment: I think using `Promise.resolve(null)` to wrap is simpler than creating a new Promise with the executor?

Comment: @Olegzandr Well it depends on the definition of "simple", I thought the "simple" means to fix the problem with as little change to the source as possible. If yours is different, please clarify that. Just bear in mind that `Promise.resolve(arg)` is alias for `new Promise(resolve => resolve(arg))`, and every `.then` is creating a new promise object in chain. That's why in some sense calling `new Promise()` is simpler, because you don't have to create additional promise and don't have to put through the magical placeholder values like `null`.