# How to handle UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am using Javascript fetch API to post data to a json server. But I am getting UnhandledPromiseRejection Warning. Below is the code, plese help in finding the issue in the code.

```
function addFavourite(movieid) {
        if (!favMovies.find(x => x.id == movieid)) {
            let movie=movies.find((x)=>x.id==movieid);
            //console.log(movie);
            //addFavourite(movie);
            return fetch("http://localhost:3000/favourites", {
                method: "POST",
                headers:{
                    "Contenet-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(movie),
            }).then((response) => {
                favMovies.push(movie);
                return response.json();
            }).then((response)=>{
                return response;
            }).catch((error)=>{
                return (error);
            });;
        } else {
            throw new Error('Movie is already added to favourites');
      } 
}
```

> (node:7358) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: AssertionError: expected
>   { Object (voteCount, id, ...) } to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]: expected
>   { Object (message, showDiff, ...) } to equal null (node:7358)
>   [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
>   deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Your code looks good, but your error looks like you are using this in some test case, right? The problem will be in your assert, not in the addFavourite method.

Comment: Assertion error? Where does that come from? Please show us the code where you are *calling* `addFavourite`

Comment: [`.then((response)=>{
                return response;
            })` is pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572), and you should not do `.catch((error)=>{
                return (error);
            })` as that doesn't really handle anything but returns an error as if it was a fulfillment result. Also [don't `throw` from a function that would return  a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887856/should-an-async-api-ever-throw-synchronously).