# Throwing errors synchronously from a function that returns an asynchronous result: antipattern?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling

Take the following contrived example:

```
function foo(input) {
  if (typeof input !== 'string') {
    // An error is thrown synchronously here
    throw new Error('input must be string');
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // Do something async here and return the result
  });
}
```

Here, an error is thrown synchronously while the result of the computation is returned asynchronously. I know this can be easily overcome by rejecting with the error inside of the promise (or better yet, using an `async` function and throwing from inside of that), but does the above pattern introduce any strange behavior or is it considered an "antipattern" in any way?

Comment: `foo().catch(err => {})` will see strange behaviour - the error is caught depending on whether it is a synchronous exception or an asynchronous rejection.

Comment: @j_maes54 - I've migrated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65524149/157247) to the question Bergi quite correctly marked. Happy coding!