# Is returning a promise from a non-async function and allowing synchronous error a meaningful pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

While looking TypeORM code, I found that `EntityManager.count()` method is a non-async function, but it returns a promise, so the developer can use `await` for this.

However, in this method, `setFindOptions()` can throw an error synchronously. I understood, that the difference between asynchronous error and synchronous error is that asynchronous error just returns a pending promise and waits until the execution context meets await, but synchronous errors just throw continuously until a `catch` is met.

So `count()` can ignore an `await` statement, even though it was intended to be asynchronous.

Now, if I use `Promise.all`, and call `count()` before, call asynchronous function which will throw an asynchronous error, then the asynchronous function cannot meet `await` forever, thus an unhandled rejection occurs and the server will stop.

So I think, that all functions which return a promise should be asynchronous, but the `find()` method was asynchronous function, so I wonder what was the intent.

I tried to wrap the `count` function in an asynchronous function, but if there was an intent, I thought that asking about the usage is the better way.

Comment: I would generally considered that an anti-pattern unless there's some really, really good reason to throw a synchronous exception and it is documented to high hell.  If you return a promise, a developer will EXPECT that errors come via a rejection on that promise.  Now, if you do do an `await` on the function call and do put a `try/catch` around that `await`, that will handle both synchronous exceptions and rejected promises.  But, if you decide to use `.then()` and `.catch()` on that promise, those won't catch the synchronous exception.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887856/should-an-async-api-ever-throw-synchronously

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @jfriend00! Is there any specific case of "really good reason" in your mind? Thanks to link @Bergi provided which I couldn't search, I was able to know that the pattern of always returning promise is even decided by w3 standard, and that's why tc39 made async function to change exception in synchronous context to asynchronous exception. However, I don't know why they opened the option of not using async keyword to function which returns promise, and I guess there is a counterexample, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @queueueue - I don't know of any good reason. I would likely NEVER code to throw a synchronous exception from a function that returns a promise.  It's just a pain in the ass function to use if it does that.  Just use an `async` function and ANY synchronous exception that is thrown will automatically be caught and turned into a rejected promise for you.