# Rejecting Javascript Promises And Error Handling

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around the correct way to indicate a failure within a `.then()`.

If the promise doesn't fail, (I.e. the operation that returns the promise does it' job properly, such as an AJAX request that returns a status 200), but I decide that the result isn't valid, usually I'd do a popup, explaining the issue to the user, and do a "return false;" to exit the method early.

However, with promises, if from within the .then(), I want to do something similar, I've been lead to believe that what I should do is throw an error instead, and presumably let this get caught by the .catch() that I've chained on.

My concern is that I want to distinguish between an operation within a promise that succeeded, but which I don't like the result of, and a failed operation within a promise.

For example, if I perform an AJAX call and it fails with a 404, that's not really recoverable, so it seems appropriate to reject with a popup saying something like "something went wrong".

However, if the AJAX request is successful (returns a status 200), but the response indicates that something isn't right (Like the user didn't fill out a field with a correct value), then I'd like to handle that a certain way, which might involve not just a popup with a message (e.g. maybe DOM manipulations, red text etc, things that I might not want to do if it's a 404).

Below are 2 examples to better explain what I mean.

The first being the original implementation with callbacks and the second being with promises (Wrapping the ajax call with the Q promise library to make it a proper promise).

Callback version:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "/cars/1",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
})
.done(function (data) {
    if (!data.IsSuccessful) {
        //The request was successful (status 200), but the server is returning IsSuccessful=false
        alert(data.Message);//message says something like "we have that car in our catalogue but we don't have it in stock"
        return false;//early exit from .done()
    }

    //if it gets here, everything is good and I can do something with the result
})
.fail(function (data) {
    //The request actually failed due to a generic status 500 error which has something I don't necessarily want to expose in a popup to the user
    alert("Something went wrong");

});
```

Promise version:

```
    var myPromise = Q(
    $.ajax({
        url: "/cars/1",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    })
);

myPromise.then(function (data) {
    if (!data.IsSuccessful) {
        throw new Error(data.Message);
    }

    //all good, lets do something with the result
})
.catch(function (error) {

    //what is error?
    //How do I know if it's one that I want to show to the user or not?

}).done();
```

In the promise version, if the request returns a 404 it will end up in the `.catch()` immediately right?

If `data.IsSuccessful==false`, then it will also end up in the `.catch()`?

What if I want to treat both failures differently, how would I go about that?

I'm not calling resolve or reject anywhere, is that problematic?

I'd like to make sure I'm following best practices as much as possible.

Comment: Why not just rely on status codes to do their job? Why would you serve up a 200 response with a `isSuccessful: false` property in it? The 2xx response codes all mean that the request *was successful*.

Comment: Because he might want to display some value that can only be retrieved by the database and thus needs to return this value to the client. This gives a status 200 from AJAX.

Comment: @Abayob can return data in headers for non `200`

Comment: @charlietfl How? And can you interpret that with JavaScript? Do you have an example?

Comment: @Abayob you set header message at server and check response status and if it is a custom status read the header which is part of $.ajax xhr object

Comment: @charlietfl Oke, nice. I rest my case!

Comment: @meagar you're right, I knew someone would make that point.  My example isn't great.
What I'm trying to get across is, if the operation returns a 200, but I want to throw based on something in the result, I'd like to treat that custom logic throw differently to how I would with a 404 for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You *can* use [rejections for control flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572), but in general they are for [exceptional cases only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21617531/1048572)

---

> In the promise version, if the request returns a 404 it will end up in the .catch() immediately right?

Yes.

> If data.IsSuccessful==false, then it will also end up in the .catch()?

Yes.

> I'm not calling resolve or reject anywhere, is that problematic?

Not at all. You're not using the `Promise` constructor (which you don't need, as you already have a promise for the ajax result).

> What if I want to treat both failures differently, how would I go about that?

Throw different kinds of errors so that you can distinguish them. Give them names, add special properties, do subclassing (in ES6 especially), or just look at the message.

> with promises, if from within the .then(), I want to do something similar, I've been lead to believe that what I should do is throw an error instead

Not necessarily. You can do exactly the same as you did without promises - put an if-else in the callback (or an if with an early return if you prefer).

In terms of control flow and their result values,

```
.then(function(res) {
    if (!res.isOK) {
        // do something
        return false;
    }
    // do something else
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle something
})
```

and

```
.then(function(res) {
     if (!res.isOK)
         throw new MyError(res);
     // do something else
}).catch(function(err) {
     if (err instanceof MyError) {
         // do something
         return false;
     }
     // handle something
})
```

are pretty much equivalent (except for exceptions in `do something` and with code other than this throwing `MyError`s). The major difference is when you want to chain additional `.then(…)` invocations between the `then` and `catch`. If you don't, just choose whatever you like better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you please clarify your last paragraph for me?
Are you saying that if I do want to chain additional .then()s off of the .then() that I'm throwing an exception from, I need to be mindful that they wont get called as it will jump straight to the .catch()?

Comment: @Steviebob: Yes, exactly. That might or might not be exactly what you want. If you don't want to get them called and still want to use `if`-`else`, you can nest the `then` callbacks though.