# How to avoid using promise catch to control program?

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise

A piece of codes:

```
// file defined here.
return getFile.then(function _gotFile(file) { // getFile is a promise, resolved OR rejected
  // A
  // do something on file
  return file;
})
  .catch(function() {
    // B
    // do other things on file, 
    return file;
  })
```

In the above piece of codes, I am using `promise catch` to control program flow: if `getFile` promise resolved, do `A`, otherwise, do `B`.

Is it good practice to write codes like this?

How to rewrite the above piece of codes to avoid this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is how you should do it.

Comment: where are you returning the file in `then` and `catch` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `getFile` promise resolved, do A, otherwise, do B.

Actually, no. It also does B when A failed. If you really want "otherwise", then you [need to use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). See also [Correct Try...Catch Syntax Using Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44663864/1048572).

> Is it good practice to write codes like this?

Yes, and no. It depends.

It is totally normal to make control flow decisions with exceptions. If something fails, it is definitely a good practice to handle the error.

On the other hand, you can overuse exceptions. Sometimes returning a boolean value or result type enum or something similar through the fulfillment case, and distinguishing it using `if`/`else`, can be much simpler.

Also, when you are using exceptions/rejections, you need to beware and use them right. JS only has `catch`-all, no conditional exceptions, and doing it manually is cumbersome. Still, it is usually a good practice to catch only specific kinds of errors that you actually can handle, and to rethrow others. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365692/1048572) for an exacmple.